# How to use apf:strsplit in Jena:fuseki

Tags: function, sparql, jena, strsplit, fuseki

I'm trying to use the function apf:strsplit in order to split values of a datatype property. I looked for some examples and did like indicated there, however, in my case the fuseki returns an error.

My query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX apf: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/property#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?s ?member
where{
  ?s a dbo:MusicalArtist .
  ?s dbp:hometown ?p .
  {select ?member
    where{
      ?member apf:strSplit(?p " ") . 
    }
   }
}
```

The result:

```
Error 500: ?/p is not a literal node
Fuseki - version 2.3.1 (Build date: 2015-12-08T09:24:07+0000)
```

Example of my instances:

```
<http://example.com/resource/6>
  rdf:type dbo:Actor ;
  rdf:type dbo:MusicalArtist ;
  rdf:type dbo:Person ;
  rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
  dbo:bloodGroup "n"@en ;
  dbo:spouse <http://example.com/resource/11> ;
  dbo:spouseName "Angelina Jolie" ;
  dbp:hometown "Dallas"^^xsd:string ;
  foaf:name "Brad Pettitt" ;
.
<http://example.com/resource/17>
  rdf:type dbo:MusicalArtist ;
  rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
  dbp:hometown "El Paço"^^xsd:string ;
  foaf:name "Harrison Ford" ;
.
```

When I change ?p by "other text", it works and result in:

```
1 <http://example.com/resource/6>  "other"
2 <http://example.com/resource/6>  "text"
3 <http://example.com/resource/3>  "other"
4 <http://example.com/resource/3>  "text"
```

I tried put str(?p), ?p^^xsd:string ?p^^xsd:literal but nothing work.
I looked on the Internet, but I did not find anything that I can use.

Anybody has some suggestion how can I fix this query? I have no idea :-( Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advances,

Regards,

Valéria

Comment: I guess the value for `dbp:hometown` is not always a literal. If you took the data from DBpedia, you should be aware of the fact, that properties of the `http://dbpedia.org/property/` namespace are not typed, i.e. there is no distinction between object and data properties, thus, the value can be both, a URI and a literal.

Comment: Do you have to use a sub-select or what's the reason for? And what happens if you use `apf:strSplit(str(?p) " ") . `

Comment: I thought it was necessary to use nested query when using strSplit. I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a nested SELECT which will be evaluated and the results combined with the earlier part - `SELECT ?member` hides the `?p` inside - in effect it is a different variable (and ARQ renamed it to `?/p`).

Just drop the inner SELECT:

```
select ?s ?member
where{
  ?s a dbo:MusicalArtist .
  ?s dbp:hometown ?p .
  ?member apf:strSplit(?p " ") . 
   }
}
```